# React prop-types error

Tags: reactjs, codepen, react-router-dom

I'm trying to create web app in codepen. I'm using React, ReactDOM. All was fine. But when I added react-router-dom to my project, I got an error:

```
react-router-dom.min.js:1 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "prop-types"
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Add the missing dependencies... See also the dependencies section in https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-dom

Comment: Please see: [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags)

Comment: I use npm but not cnpm and yarn,it works!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As of React 15.5.0, PropTypes have been removed from the core React package as a separate dependency. To fix this, add `prop-types` into your code:

If you're loading via script tags:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/prop-types/prop-types.min.js"></script>
```

Or via NPM:

```
npm install --save prop-types
```

Answer (score 5):

This is due to prop-type being missing. It can be added using your package manager.

If you're using npm:

```
npm install prop-types --save
```

If you're using yarn:

```
yarn add prop-types
```

Comment: When adding an answer to an older question with existing accepted answers it can be helpful to point out what new information your answer brings to the question.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the lates UMD build at:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-router-dom/umd/react-router-dom.min.js"></script>
```

is currently missing a dependence on prop-types.  You can use version 4.0.0 instead for the time being to avoid this error:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/react-router-dom@4.0.0/umd/react-router-dom.min.js"></script>
```